# Where is the PowerPoint Service Application?

Tags: powerpoint-services

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837424.aspx) provides a nice set of instructions for configuring PowerPoint Services.

Excerpt:

> 2) In the Central Administration Web
>   site, in the Application Management
>   section, click Manage service
>   applications.
>
> 3) On the Service
>   Applications page, click PowerPoint
>   Service Application

Only one problem... There is no "PowerPoint Service Application" link present.  Furthermore there are no Powershell commands related to PowerPoint available to me such as Get-SPPowerPointServiceApplication.

Can someone tell me where to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to install the Office Web Apps - it is a separate install and separate download from MSDN.

Comment: Do you have the link handy?

Comment: Found it here:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 you will not be able to see PowerPoint Service Application. Use below PowerShell command to create PowerPoint Service Application.

1. Run PowerShell Command using administrator.
2. Perform as per below script,

   ```
       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy            
       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> $SAProxy= Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy |?{$_.DisplayName -eq "PowerPoint Automation Service Applications Proxy"}

       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> $SAProxy 

       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup 

       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup |?{$_.FriendlyName -eq "[default]"} 


       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> $SAGroup= Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup |?{$_.FriendlyName -eq "[default]"}

       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> $SAGroup 

       PS C:\Users\spAdmin> Add-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroupMember $SAGroup -Member $SAProxy
   ```